# Proving $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k} = 2^{2n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

I'm undergraduate student of mathematics. 
I need to prove:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k}= 2^{2n-1}$$
Can you please help me

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530676/prove-sum-i-0n-binom2n1i-22n

Answer (score 16):

Expand $\dfrac{(1+x)^{2n}+(1-x)^{2n}}2$ and then plug in $x=1$.

Comment: Sum is up to $\large n$.

Comment: @Felix but the lower index in the binomial coefficient is $2k$.

Comment: @RyanReich $0$k. I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Consider
$$
(1+x)^{2n} = \sum_{j=0}^{2n} {2n \choose j}x^j
$$

1. Plug in $x=-1$ : Divide the above expression into those $j$'s that are even, and those that are odd. Those sums must equal each other.
2. Plug in $x=1$ : You get $2^{2n}$ on the LHS; while the RHS is a sum of the even and odd sums from (1).

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n}{2k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \left[\binom{2n - 1}{2k} + \binom{2n - 1}{2k - 1}\right] = \sum_{k=-1}^{2n} \binom{2n - 1}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n - 1} \binom{2n - 1}{k} = 2^{2n-1} $$

Comment: Quite clear. Up Vote $0$k.